# REST API in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, spring-security

I created a REST API but every time I try to access it it takes me to the login page of my app. I want to use the REST API independently with specific *userid* and *password*. The url I created is like:

```
/PageCreation?OrId=90&prid=23
```

Each time it tries to access it it appends ws to it and URL then becomes like

```
ws/PageCreation?OrId=90&prid=23
```

If i check the mapping in application.security.xml it is like below:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/ws/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

Also the below code is also there:

```
<beans:bean id="dummyProvider" class="com.AuthenticationProvider">
<beans:constructor-arg ref="userS" />               
    </beans:bean>
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userS">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

In AuthenticationProvider we have authenticate method.

Comment: It is not the mapping but are the beans. Post the mapping file. Plus the api controller class for better understanding.

Comment: The web.xml has below : <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> and controller class has  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getNTemp",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
      protected ResponseEntity<Map<String,Set<NHelper>>> getProject
      (@RequestParam(value = "orId", required = true) Long orId,
    @RequestParam(value = "prid", required = true) Integer prid,
    HttpServletRequest request) {

Comment: Madam, you have problem with /PageCreation mapping, why are you showing me mapping of something else.